# Доступ к полю редактирования

Tags: ckeditor

Необходимо из плагина обратиться к текущему полю редактора и удалить один из его классов. Представленный ниже код не работает:

```
        exec: function(editor) {
            editor.removeClass('myclass');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery( editor.element.$ ).removeClass('myclass');
```

Comment: Так работать не хочет.